# CSS Div and li spacing issue

Tags: css, html, html-lists

How do I get the `div` to have the 1 px border on the bottom? Instead of that thick grey bar.
The `div` that holds the `ul` with `id="widget-content"` has a white background with a 1px padding to give the 1px border impression.

No matter what I do, if I try to collapse the widget-content `div` or expand the li `div`. There can be more than 3 `li` in the `ul`.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
```

```
  <div id="widget-head">
 <h3><a href="#" target="_blank">CHANNEL</a></h3>
      <div id="widget-edit"><img src="images/icons/settings_g.png" width="12" height="12"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="widget-content">
      <ul id="widget-feeds">
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#" > <img src="images/icons/hidden.gif" name="123311"> </a> <a href="#" target="_blank" title="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet tortor sit amet nunc interdum</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="widget-desc">
        <p>description text here</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#" > <img src="images/icons/hidden.gif" name="123311"> </a> <a href="#" target="_blank" title="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet tortor sit amet nunc interdum</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="widget-desc">
        <p>description text here</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div>
        <a href="#" > <img src="images/icons/hidden.gif" name="123311"> </a> <a href="#" target="_blank" title="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet tortor sit amet nunc interdum</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="widget-desc">
        <p>description text here</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**And my relevant CSS**

```
    #content #widget-container {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-head {
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 25px;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-head h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-head #widget-edit {
    float: right;
    width: 12px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 1px;

}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds ul {
overflow: auto;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds li {
    display: block;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds li a {


}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds li .widget-desc {
    white-space: normal;
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visible greyness at the bottom is not a border, it's actually due to the unordered list's bottom margin, which creates an empty space at the bottom.

The following will eliminate this space:

```
#widget-feeds { margin-bottom: 0 }
#widget-feeds li { margin-bottom: 0 !important; padding: 4px 0 9px 0 !important; }
```

Note that my fix above is not good practice, you should edit your existing stylesheet to meet these changes instead of applying the rules I specified here.

Comment: Sorry that didn't fix it.

Comment: @JasonBourne Right, the issue is also with the list item's bottom margin. See my edited answer please

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! It was the margin spacing. GAAAAH!